# Read RFID tag with Parallax RFID module

Tags: rfid

I'm using [Parallax RFID Read/Write Module - Serial](https://www.parallax.com/product/28440), this [datasheet](https://www.parallax.com/sites/default/files/downloads/28440-28540-RFID-Read-Write-Documentation-v2.1.pdf) and trying to set module in active mode (LED light goes from GREEN to RED) with python code and then actually read tag. After running testing code, module is still in passive mode (LED stays GREEN)

Connections from reference:

[image]

Raspberry PI 4 wiring:

[image]

Testing code:

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

ENABLE_PIN = 23
SERIAL_PIN = 24

# The reader has an ENABLE pin, which must be LOW to read
GPIO.setup(ENABLE_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SERIAL_PIN, GPIO.IN)

# This just makes a flash of the LED
print('high')
GPIO.output(ENABLE_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(1)

print('low')
GPIO.output(ENABLE_PIN, GPIO.LOW)

input()
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Please advice

Comment: Don't connect any 5V device to GPIO pins without a voltage divider or buffer chip, you will make your Raspberry Pi die a sad and awful death if you burn it out with 5V.

Comment: I can see nothing in the linked pdf which suggests doing what you have done will change the status LED.  Don't connect 5V to a PI GPIO.

Comment: @joan (cite) When the module is successfully powered-up and is in an idle state, the LED will be GREEN;
when the module is in an active state (for example, searching for a valid tag or performing an operation
on the tag), the LED will be RED.

Comment: You need to send serial data.  Just toggling a GPIO does not do that.  You probably need to connect to the UART TX/RX GPIO (with a suitable drop down circuit from 5V to 3V3 on the Pi's RX GPIO).